# Opinionated Javascript, Passing Resolvers not working (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In simple, I'm adapting a simple example to get some practice with [opinionated javascript produced by Todd Motto](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/).

**[Plunkr Of Issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/iYDG7QQ4w8EriX266gcc?p=preview)**  As described originally

**[Plunkr Of using a Resolver](http://plnkr.co/edit/7TEO7vcqF2jkvzahfWbZ?p=preview)** Using traditional resolver

The problem is that my resolver does not have access to the factories queried results.  I am not sure why, but the ways I have found to do this are too hackish.  What is best way to pass resolved objects here?

In this example I have a simple MVVM page that contains a div with controllerAs syntax.

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectCtrl as vm">
    <h1>Hello: {{vm.message}}</h1>
</div>
```

And here is the configuration of opinionated javascript.

```
'use strict';

(function(){
  /* Module & Dependencies */
  angular.module('project', ['ui.router']);
  angular.module('project').factory('Project', Project);
  angular.module('project').controller('ProjectCtrl', ProjectCtrl);
  angular.module('project').config(ProjectStates);


  /* Factory */
  function Project($resource){
    return $resource('app/rest/projects/:id', {}, {
      'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
      'get': { method: 'GET'}
    });
  };

  /* Controller */
  function ProjectCtrl(Project){
    var model = this;
    /* No access to anything that's resolved */

    model.message = "World";
  };

  ProjectCtrl.resolve = {
    projectResolver: function(Project, $q){
      return Project.query();
    }
  }


  /* Routes */
  function ProjectStates($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
    /* Default state and parent to all project states */
    $stateProvider.state('project',{
      url: "/project",
      templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
      resolve: ProjectCtrl.resolve
    });    
  };


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your queried result via **dependency injection**:

```
function ProjectCtrl(Project, projectResolver){
  var model = this;

  // now use your queried result, e.g.
  model.projects = projectResolver;

  model.message = "World";
};
```

But this only works if you define your controller and controllerAs properties in the state object:

```
$stateProvider.state('project',{
  url: "/project",
  templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
  resolve: ProjectCtrl.resolve,
  controller: "ProjectCtrl",
  controllerAs: "vm"                                                  
});
```

Now the **Html** should look like this:

```
...
<body>
    <ui-view>
</body>
...
```

And the **views/projects.html** file can be something like the following:

```
<h1>Hello {{vm.message}}!</h1>
<ul><li ng-repeat='project in vm.projects' ng-bind='project.name'></li></ul>
```

Here is a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwf5qLje/)**

Comment: Now, I'm getting this: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: projectResolverProvider <- projectResolver

Comment: Thanks. Removing the ng-controller on the div and everything flew and moving it to the router as described here.  The jsfiddle helped great, thanks.